# Trying to bind Dropdownlist from db getting error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

hi i am trying to bind Dropdownlist from value coming from db getting error
details are as below
Model

```
public class Ipcell
{  public List<ddlupc> upcList { get; set; }
}
    public class ddlupc
    {
     public string UscCode { get; set; }
    public string UscDesc { get; set; }
    
}
```

controller
is being called from jquery Ajax value is coming

```
public PartialViewResult RaiseBill(List<Ipcell> casedetail1)
        {List<Ipcell> result1 = new List<Ipcell>();
            conn.Open();
            string qry1 = "select IUM_USC_CODE,IUM_USC_DESC from V_IP_USC_MAST";
            OracleCommand command1 = new OracleCommand(qry1, conn);
            OracleDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
            List<ddlupc> objlist = new List<ddlupc>();
            Ipcell member1 = new Ipcell();
            while (reader1 != null && reader1.Read())
            {               

            objlist.Add(new ddlupc { UscCode = reader1[0].ToString(), UscDesc = reader1[1].ToString() });
             result1.Add(member1);
            }
            member1.upcList = objlist;
            conn.Close();
  if (casedetail1!=null)
            {
                ViewBag.Caseid = casedetail1[0].CaseId;
            }
            
            return PartialView("RaiseBill", result1);          

        }
```

view

```
@model Smart_M.Models.Ipcell
<div>
<div style="padding-left:5%">Usc Code</div><span style="padding-left:5%">@Html.DropDownList("upcList",Model.upcList) </span><br />
</div>
```

Getting Error "Cannot convert from 'System.collections.Generic.List<Smart_M.Models.ddlupc> to 'string'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Getting Error "Cannot convert from
> 'System.collections.Generic.List<Smart_M.Models.ddlupc> to 'string'.
> Any idea would be appreciated.

Because the data source bound to the `@Html.DropDownList` is of type **`IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`**, but `Model.upcList` is of type `List<ddlupc>`,which caused an error.

To solve it, you can **convert Model.upcList into IEnumerable form**, as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("upcList", new SelectList(Model.upcList, "UscCode", "UscDesc"))
```

You can also refer to [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-bind-the-value-to-razor-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc5/) for more ways to bind dropdownlist in asp.net core.

### Update

```
public PartialViewResult RaiseBill(List<Ipcell> casedetail1)
        {List<Ipcell> result1 = new List<Ipcell>();
            conn.Open();
            string qry1 = "select IUM_USC_CODE,IUM_USC_DESC from V_IP_USC_MAST";
            OracleCommand command1 = new OracleCommand(qry1, conn);
            OracleDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
            List<ddlupc> objlist = new List<ddlupc>();
            Ipcell member1 = new Ipcell();
            while (reader1 != null && reader1.Read())
            {               

            objlist.Add(new ddlupc { UscCode = reader1[0].ToString(), UscDesc = reader1[1].ToString() });
             result1.Add(member1);
            }
            member1.upcList = objlist;
            conn.Close();
  if (casedetail1!=null)
            {
                ViewBag.Caseid = casedetail1[0].CaseId;
            }

            ViewData["dropSrc"] = objlist ;
            return PartialView("RaiseBill", result1);          

        }
```

RaiseBill View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Smart_M.Models.Ipcell> 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "IncellTest";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} 

<div>
    <div style="padding-left:5%">Usc Code</div>
    <span style="padding-left:5%">@Html.DropDownList("upcList", new SelectList((IEnumerable<Smart_M.Models.ddlupc>)ViewData["dropSrc"], "UscCode", "UscDesc")) </span>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: @yongging i tried but getting error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Smart_M.Models.Ipcell]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Smart_M.Models.Ipcell'

Comment: @Mohan, this error shows the model put back by the action corresponding to the view is `List<Ipcell>`, and your view refers to `Ipcell`, you can change the view model to  `@model IEnumerable<Smart_M.Models.Ipcell>`. But this will conflict with your dropdownlist data source. I hope you clarify your needs and provide a complete code, otherwise we cannot provide you with the correct solution.

Comment: @Mohan, If the data passed from the action to the view is a collection of data, then `Model.upcList` will no longer hold. If the dropdownlist data source is fixed, then you can use `ViewData` in the action and bind `List<ddlupc>` to the dropdownlist.

Comment: @Mohan, I have updated my reply based on your code and requirement, hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

DropDownList uses SelectListItem for data binding example:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Names", new List<SelectListItem>  
{  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="NAME1", Value = "1" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="NAME2", Value = "2" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="NAME3", Value = "3" },   
})
```

Please change Model.upcList to List for example:

```
<div style="padding-left:5%">Usc Code</div>
<span style="padding-left:5%">
@Html.DropDownList("upcList",Model.upcList.Select(x => new SelectListItem(){Text  
 = x.UscDesc ,Value = x.UscCode }).ToList())
</span>
```

OR

```
<div style="padding-left:5%">Usc Code</div>
<span style="padding-left:5%">
@Html.DropDownList("upcList", new SelectList(Model.upcList,"UscCode", "UscDesc"))
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding Dropdown at View

a. We can bind the dropdown list using HTML.Dropdownlist (it is an HTML helper class).

ListItems: <%= Html.DropDownList("ListItems")%>

Here we are passing "ListItems" that have been passed from the controller to the view.

b. Another overloaded method of the HTML.DropdownList class for binding a dropdown list.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("SelectedItem", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ListItems"])%>
```

Check proper above code then after implement.